# Fill a path polygon with gradient

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm drawing a polygon using `path` in javascript , and I'd like to fill it by linear gradient. Unfortunately it doesn't work and in return whole shape turns into black. I know that it works with `rect` ,

Any idea on how to solve the problem ?

```
    <g>
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="LineChartGradient">
                <stop offset="5%"  stopColor="green"/>
                <stop offset="95%" stopColor="gold"/>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path d={path(fillPoints)} stroke={color} strokeWidth='0' fill='url(#LinearChartGradient)' fillOpacity='0.5'/>
    </g>
```

(Note: I use react, therefore the attribute names are little different from normal ! It doesn't affect the html structure. As I said I tried it with `rect` and it works)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle that shows your React code?

Comment: I believe that it's off topic and not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that we cannot add linearGradient fill to a polygon created by `path`. What I did was to use `polygon` instead of `path`.

Answer (score -1):

You've made a typo in your fill declaration. The ID isn't the same as in the definition. Change it to `fill='url(#LineChartGradient)'`. 
Also, your  elements are using incorrect attributes for the stopcolor. Use `stop-color` instead. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient for a better look around

Comment: Actually I mentioned that I'm using React and that's due to react that I write it stopColor , by the way , it looks like that `path` doesn't get Gradient fill , therefore I decided to use Polygon